# Play framework 2.3.8: I cannot set the environment variable neither on Windows 7 nor on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, playframework-2.3

Here are the specific settings right now of the environment variables window of my Windows 7:
Variable name: activator
Variable value: C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\Client_Folders\activator-1.3.2-minimal
Variable name: Java
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin
Variable name: Javac
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin
And when I issue an activator command I get the following errors:
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.76011
Copyright  2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Users\Bryan>activator new
'activator' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or hatch file.

C:\Users\Bryan>cd C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\Client_Folders\activator-1.3.2-minima
1
C:\Users\Bryan\Documents\Client_Polders\activator-1_3_2-minimanal>activator new

A Java JDK is not installed or can't be found.
Please go to
 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
and download a valid Java JDK and install before running Activator.
If you think this message is in error, please check
your environment variables to see if "java.exe" and "javac.exe" are
available via JAvA_HOME or PATH.

For the Ubuntu machine I followed some precise instructions on how to download the Play framework and the JDK, and setting the environment paths but I am getting errors there too. If you can tell me what command's output you need, I will supply them.

Thanks a million for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mkay, two things:

**1. You didn't pay much attention when reading the docs.**

For the activator environment variable:

> This means update the PATH in the environment variables and don’t use a path with spaces.

Ergo: edit the existing PATH env. var and insert there the path to your activator. DO NOT create another user env. var. like you did(e.g. activator)

**2. You're not setting your JAVA_HOME properly**

Replace the Java and Javac env. vars with JAVA_HOME = path_to_your_java

After successfully completing **1 + 2** restart your CLI and everything will work just fine.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much sebster. I did what you asked but doing #2 caused the two (java and javac) env.vars to be consolidated to one (JAVA_HOME), as they are in the same folder. I can now run the activator commands from outside the Play Framework folder, but I still get the java env.vars error. What have I done wrong this time?

Comment: No no no... For the Java env vars,  you should remove java and javac and leave only the JAVA_HOME one. I wasn't clear enough, my bad.